# Is it okay not to close db for sqlite3

Tags: ruby

Here is my method

```
def convertElsToMass(symbol)
    begin
       db = SQLite3::Database.open("test.db")

       rs = db.prepare("SELECT * FROM Elements WHERE symbol = '#{symbol}    '")
       temp = rs.execute
       mass = temp.first

       rescue SQLite3::Exeption => e
            puts e

       ensure
            db.close if db
    end       
    return mass[3]   
end
```

When I test this method using rspec I get this error message:

```
 1) PeriodicTable should change Elements to mass of Elements
 Failure/Error: expect(table.convertElsToMass("Na")).to eq(22.9898)
 SQLite3::BusyException:
   unable to close due to unfinalized statements or unfinished backups
 # ./lib/formatel.rb:42:in `close'
 # ./lib/formatel.rb:42:in `convertElsToMass'
 # ./spec/lib/pt_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I notice I if I don't put the line `db.close if db` this method does exactly as I expect. However I'm worried what the consequences are if I don't close the db after I execute a query. How can I fix this so that I close the db after I execute a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about closing the database. When you call `prepare` or `execute`, those calls are automatically call close when they are done. There is an internal `rescue/ensure` block that ensures the db is closed even if an error is raised. You can see this in the source code for [SQLite3::Database](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/blob/6c0d6f996bf224eaa07ab6123647193b1b5d19d4/lib/sqlite3/database.rb#L90-L99).

Comment: That closes the statement, not the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Very late but let me answer your question and suggest a fix aswell:

> Is it okay not to close db for sqlite3

It depends on how long your code is running and how many times you open the database during said runtime. If it happens a lot, then you can run out of the file descriptors you are allowed to open (usually 1024 on most Linux distributions). Therefore (and obviously to prevent memory issues), you should always close your database, especially if you intend to run the script over a longer period of time.

The fix for this issue is that you have to finalize the SQLite statement (see [sqlite_finalize](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html)). In ruby's sqlite3, you do this by calling `.close` on the statement.

So in your code, after the `temp = rs.execute` you simply have to add a `rs.close` to close and finalize the statement. Once the statement is closed your database won't be busy anymore and you can close it.